# python check if item exist then print item

Tags: python, list, if-statement

i have a dictionary as such:

```
   my_dict= { documents : [{a:1,b:2},
                           {a:3},
                           {a:4,b:5}
                          ]
             }
```

I would like to print only the values of b.

Here is my code:

```
for item in my_dict[documents]:
    print item[b]
```

However this code keeps giving me an error probably because the key 'b' does not exist in every item.

I changed my code to take into consideration of the exceptions:

```
for item in my_dict[documents]:
    if not item[b]:
        print "NONE"
    else:
        print item[b]
```

this doesnt seem to work. what do i need to change in my code to make it work?

Thanks,

Comment: Your code is fine. You just need to surround the keys with single quotes, both when you define it and when you extract the value using the key. You do need to include the `if` statement though to check if the key is exists.

Comment: Zaphod, you're probably right about the lack of intended quotes, but the OP's code will fail on the second dictionary (`{"a":3}`) anyway because it doesn't contain the key `"b"`.

Comment: @DanLenski. Well that's why checking for the key is necessary. `if 'b' in item:`.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's current code does **not** check for the existence of the key correctly. `if d[missing_key]: ...` will raise an error with Python's standard `dict` class, and this is by design. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25839807/20789) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, and multiple ways to fix it. Here is a fairly minimal set of changes that will do it:

1. The way you have defined your data structure, it refers to variables `a`,`b`,and `documents`. I am guessing that you mean to use the literal strings instead:

   ```
   my_dict= { "documents" : [{"a":1,"b":2},
                          {"a":3},
                          {"a":4,"b":5}
                         ]
            }
   ```
2. Assuming that (1) is correct, `d[key]` will always raise a `KeyError` if `key` does not occur in the dictionary, at least for the standard `dict` class. One solution is to use `d.get(key, DEFAULTVALUE)` which [will substitute a specified default value for a missing key](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). The solution that is closes to your current code is the following:

   ```
   for item in my_dict["documents"]:
       if "b" in item:
           print item["b"]
       else:
           print "NONE"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you cannot do `{key: 0}` -- instead, you need to do `{'key': 0}` (make the key a string, number, or some previously-defined object)

The fixed version of your code would look something like this:

```
my_dict= { 
    'documents' : [
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 3},
        {'a': 4, 'b': 5}
    ]
}

for item in my_dict['documents']:
    if 'b' in item:
        print item['b']
    else:
        print 'NONE'
```

Note that this behavior differs from Javascript, where if you do `{a: b}`, `a` will automatically be converted into a string.

You can make your code shorter by using the `get` method, which lets you specify a default value if the provided key doesn't exist within the dict:

```
for item in my_dict['documents']:
    print item.get('b', 'NONE')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get` to get a *default value*:

```
for item in my_dict['documents']:
    print item.get('b', 'NONE')
```

For other purposes, you may use `in` to see if the key exists:

```
if 'b' in item:
    print "item['b'] exists!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
DoLoD=my_dict= { 'documents' : [{'a':1,'b':2},
                       {'a':3},
                       {'a':4,'b':5}
                      ]
         }

for k, l in DoLoD.items():
    for d in l:
        if 'b' in d:
            print d['b']
```

Or, more tersely:

```
>>> [d['b'] for k, l in DoLoD.items() for d in l if 'b' in d] 
[2, 5]
```